# which browser (/ browser versions) support css3 border radius on img elements?

Tags: browser, cross-browser, css

Knowing that css3's border radius doesn't work on img elements in older browsers, I've added this technique of replacing img elements with div's with the image source as background image. On that div I use the border radius. This works great, but I have received feedback that sometimes users can see this transition happening in a blink.

I noticed that I am able to put border radius on img elements now using the latest firefox (6.0.2). Now my question is, how or where can I find information on which versions of which browsers, this new border radius on img elements is in effect already, so I can call the image replacement as an exception instead of on all browsers.

Thanks!
Danny

PS: i use css3pie, so this exception is helpful for many browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this article will be useful for your problem.

http://how2designweb.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-apply-border-radius-to-img-tag/

Basically, what it does is sets background image to outer div to workaround a problem with border-radius on images.

Answer (score 1):

http://muddledramblings.com/table-of-css3-border-radius-compliance/

Comment: Thanks - cool link for border-radius compliance. My question however was which browser versions support border-radius on img elements. I didn't read that in the article or did i miss that?